# Trying to write a bash script to create an excel file with specific sheet names

Tags: excel, bash, unix

I am trying to write a bash script to create an excel file using touch command. I am able to create a blank excel file, but I want to be able to create two sheets with specific names. Can someone point me in the right direction for this? Thank you.

something like -

touch blank.xlsx

Comment: This simply isn't something you can do in `bash` (at least, not without knowing the format of an Excel file). You need some other program to do it.

Comment: I guess you are correct, I would have found it by now otherwise. The application I use is a java box, I will need to look something in javascript.

Comment: the `perl` language has packages that can do full creation of `.xlsx` files. but it's not something you'll get working in a 1/2 hour. Good luck.

Comment: Using `bash` you can easily create `.csv` files. And then use [`ssconvert`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/ssconvert.1.html) to [convert them to `.xlsx`/`.xls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158254/convert-csv-to-xls-file-on-linux).

Comment: You could start LibreOffice, it has python SDK, and you could write a python program to do anything you want, passing parameters to it from bash.